# How do I chain functions returning results in Rust?

Tags: rust, error-handling, functional-programming

In the following code I would like to get the 2nd string in a vector `args` and then parse it into an `i32`. This code will not complie, however, because i can not call `parse()` on the Option value returned by `nth()`.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let a = args.iter().nth(1).parse::<i32>();
}
```

I know i could just use `expect()` to unwrap the value, before trying to parse it, however I do not want my code to panic. I want `a` to be a Result value that is an Err if either `nth()` or `parse()` fails, and otherwise is a Ok(Int). Is there a way to accomplish this in rust? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy if you look in the documentation for either `Option` or `Result`. The function you are thinking of is likely `and_then` which allows you to then provide a closure which can change the `Ok` type and value if filled, but otherwise leaves it unchanged when encountering an error. However, you need to do though is decide on a common error type to propagate. Since the `Option<&String>` needs to be turned to an error on a `None` value we have to choose a type to use.

Here I provide a brief example with a custom error type. I decided to use `.get` instead of `.iter().nth(1)` since it does the same thing and we might as well take advantage of the `Vec` since you have gone to the work of creating it.

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

enum ArgParseError {
    NotFound(usize),
    InvalidArg(ParseIntError),
}


let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let a: Result<i32, ArgParseError> = args
    .get(1)  // Option<&String>
    .ok_or_else(|| ArgParseError::NotFound(1))  // Result<&String, ArgParseError>
    .and_then(|x: &String| {
        x.parse::<i32>() // Result<i32, ParseIntError>
            .map_err(|e| ArgParseError::InvalidArg(e)) // Result<i32, ArgParseError>
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```rust
use std::{env, num::ParseIntError};

enum Error {
    ParseIntError(ParseIntError),
    Empty,
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let a: Option<Result<i32, ParseIntError>> = args.iter().nth(1).map(|s| s.parse::<i32>());
    let a: Result<i32, Error> = match a {
        Some(Ok(a)) => Ok(a),
        Some(Err(e)) => Err(Error::ParseIntError(e)),
        None => Err(Error::Empty),
    };
}
```